# How to .GroupBy multiple columns LINQ/Projection?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

How can I group by multiple columns using linq projection?

Something like this:

```
var q = db.Areas.GroupBy(x => x.AreaCatId, x.AreaCatName, x.AreaId, x.AreaName);
```

Resulting in a flat result set such as:

```
AreaCatId, AreaCatName, AreaId, AreaName
0          US           1       FL 
0          US           2       NY 
1          Canada       3       BC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can GroupBy an anonymous type:

```
var q = db.Areas.GroupBy(
            x => new 
                 {
                     CatId = x.AreaCatId, 
                     CatName = x.AreaCatName, 
                     Id = x.AreaId, 
                     Name = x.AreaName 
                 });
```

Comment: How can I sort by "Name" after the GroupBy?  I have tried GroupBy(...).OrderBy(...) and that didn't seem to work.  Thx!

Comment: @Jaj GroupBy returns an IGrouping.  If you want to flatten it, you can use: `.GroupBy(..).Select(g => g.Key).OrderBy(item => item.Name);`